# Python's osWalk to text file? only one line being printed

Tags: python, output

```
import os

searchFolder = '/Users/bubble/Desktop/pics'


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchFolder):
    for file in files:
        pathName = os.path.join(root,file)
        print pathName
        print os.path.getsize(pathName)
        print 
        f = open('/Users/bubble/Desktop/workfile.txt','w')
        f.write(pathName)
```

Only one line is being printed to the text file: /Users/bubble/Desktop/pics/IMG_2999.JPG

I want the entire output to be printed into a text file (perhaps later, even a html file that I can edit to look pretty)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the file in loop. Open once.

```
import os

searchFolder = '/Users/bubble/Desktop/pics'

with open('/Users/bubble/Desktop/workfile.txt','w') as f:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchFolder):
        for file in files:
            pathName = os.path.join(root,file)
            print pathName
            print os.path.getsize(pathName)
            print
            f.write('{}\n'.format(pathName))
            f.write('{}\n'.format(os.path.getsize(pathName)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that writes the pathName but now it wont write the getsize results

Comment: @BubbleMonster, Your code didn't write file size to the file. I change the code to write file size to output file.